# "General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value" Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

In my resource controller, in the store method, I do this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $post = $request->all();
      $post['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

      Post::create($post);

        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
```

Why am I getting the error: `General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value`?

Comment: try put static ` $post['user_id'] = 4;` and check

Comment: is your user actually logged in?
return  Auth::user()->id and see whats inside

Comment: Yes, he is logged in. The problem was that I hadn't added the `user_id` to the `protected $fillable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add 'user_id' to the $fillable attribute in your Post model to support [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

```
class Postextends Model

{
protected $fillable=['user_id']; // not only user_id but also all the fill able columns
}
```

Comment: Really! Thank you! For some reason I thought that we need to add to `$fillable` only those fields that we get from `input`.

Answer (score 0):

you shuold use user_id in fillable like this,

```
class Postextends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['user_id'];
}
```

And also you can set $guarded property as,

```
class Postextends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];
}
```

Then you not need to set propertise filable.

**Note:**
While $fillable serves as a “white list” of attributes that should be mass assignable, you may also choose to use $guarded. The $guarded property should contain an array of attributes that you do not want to be mass assignable. All other attributes not in the array will be mass assignable. So, $guarded functions like a “black list”. Of course, you should use either $fillable or $guarded — not both.